# How to change tab manually in angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I have registration form in my application. In that form im using two tabs one is for personal details form and another one is for otp verification form.

After completed filling personal details form, they have to click next, the values of personal details form should be stored in db through api call after that the verification tab have to open. In this case i dont know how to change tab (otp verification form) when next button click.

Im using ng-bootstrap tabsets. And im completely new for angular or angular 6. This is angular 6 application. Please help me.

This is my Register function (after clicking next):

```
onRegister(User: any) {
    this.spinner.show();
    if (User.user_doctor === true) {
        this.registerService.register(User)
        .subscribe((value) => {
          this.spinner.hide();
           **I want that tab changing code here**
        }, err => {
          this.spinner.hide();
          if (err.status_code === 422) {

          } else {
            console.log('Error => ', err.message);
          }
});
      setTimeout(resposne => {
        this.spinner.hide();
      }, 300);
    }
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<ngb-tabset [justify]="currentJustify" id="register" (tabChange)="beforeChange($event)">
    <ngb-tab title="personal details" id="tab-preventchange1" class="nav-no-bottom">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            <p>personal Details form</p>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="contact details" id="tab-preventchange2">
         <ng-template ngbTabContent>
              <p>otp verification form</p>
         </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
 </ngb-tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

onRegister(User: any) {
        debugger
        this.spinner.show();
        console.log(User);

```
    if (User.user_doctor === true) {
        this.registerService.register(User)
        .subscribe((value) => {
          this.spinner.hide();
          //check out this line vinothini. 
          this.isRegistered = true;
          this.showPersonalDetails();
        }, err => {
          this.spinner.hide();
          if (err.status_code === 422) {
          } else {
            console.log('Error => ', err.message);
          }
});
      setTimeout(resposne => {
        this.spinner.hide();
      }, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: public isRegistered: boolean = false;

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeChange($event: NgbTabChangeEvent) {
  //change this line in your code vinothini
  if (!this.isRegistered && $event.nextId === "tab-preventchange2") {
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of `this.isRegistered = true;` here?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.